# how to get a location click event in ModestMaps / Wax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my nice map loading from MapBox but now I need to get a click event from Wax / ModestMaps.  The following code only triggers the callback on page load:

```
var mapbg, interaction;
var urlBase = 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mteran.house';

// Build baselayer background
wax.tilejson(urlBase + '.jsonp', function(tilejson) {
  map = new MM.Map('mymap-bg',
  new wax.mm.connector(tilejson));

  map.setCenterZoom(new MM.Location(
    tilejson.center[1], // latitude
    tilejson.center[0]), // longitude
    tilejson.center[2]); // zoom level

  map.addCallback("drawn", function (map) {
    mapbg.setCenterZoom(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom());
  });

  wax.mm.zoomer(map, tilejson).appendTo(map.parent);

  map.setZoomRange(tilejson.minzoom, tilejson.maxzoom);

  wax.mm.interaction()
    .map(map)
    .tilejson(tilejson);

  var house = new MM.Location(map.getCenter());

  house.on('click', alert(map.getCenter()));

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of click event are you trying to get? [The map you're using](http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mteran.house.html#5.00/55.578/11.558) has no [TileMill interaction](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) enabled, so I'm assuming that's not the objective. If you're trying to get a click event anywhere on the map and figure out if it's on the 'house area', [here's your code expanded to make that happen](http://bl.ocks.org/3359934).

The 'close enough' will be necessary, since points are points as far as maps go; latitude/longitude locations are infinitely small and it's very hard to click them.

Comment: I was indeed trying to get a click on the house.  Your code is exactly what I needed.  Thanks a lot!